# how do you choose a receiver of expression between just-a-symbol and function?

Tags: functions, symbols

for a formula eg `y=a*x+b` in book, we can use `y=a*x+b` and use `y` to quote the expression `a*x+b` for later using. but we also can define a function `y[x_]:=a*x+b` and use `y[x]` eg `y[1]` to quote the expression for later using.
i wonder whether a choice is better in some cases and another choice is better in some cases or equal essentially? or ask this way: in which cases you will create a function(i think in most simple cases, just using a symbol to receive the right is ok)

Comment: You can explore [Scoping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) in Mathematica.

Comment: Also, `eqn1= (y==a*x+b)` is an option too.

Comment: Without specifying the application this is a open-ended question. Please [edit] your question to make it focused and clear what you are after, and make it on-topic here. In general, I would avoid global assignments and use Scoping, as suggested by Syed, but that applies to all three cases .

Comment: `y=expr`  stores the expression: expr in y. On the other hand, `f[x_]=expr` is a function with an parameter y to be replaced by an actual value.

Comment: Ideally, all dependencies should be explicit. `y[a_, b_, x_] := a*x+b` (and with descriptive variable/parameter names). This makes the code clearer and easier to maintain. Abbreviated forms are principally for quick, limited use.

Comment: Please, consider reading [Common pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users). Your questions directly relate to "how does Mathematica work?"